# PHP cookies not being deleted/unset

Tags: php, cookies

Hi I have a web in development in a remote server and a problem has come out [I unset the cookies and from that file I can see the cookies unset but in index I see them set again].

My site has the next structure (And im using MVC)
I will be as explicit as I can

```
---public_html
 --models
 --views
 --controllers
 --media
 --js
 --css
 --index.php
 --.htaccess
 --other
```

.htaccess is set so that: www.eg.eg/?view=lorem --> www.eg.eg/lorem

index calls the `views` when a parameter is set eg: www.eg.eg/some
some.php is called from views

STEPS I FOLLOW TO GET THE PROBLEM:

1. Log in `www.eg.eg/login` if cookies are available set cookie named `token`
2. Log out `www.eg.eg/other/log_out.php`
3. Check if cookies were unset but they aren't

To set cookies I do:

```
 setcookie("sessionPAD", $token, time() + (86400*30), "/", "www.eg.eg", true);
```

When I write `var_dump($_COOKIE)` in index I can see sessionPAD

To log out i do:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['x']) && isset($_SESSION['y'])){
        $x= $_SESSION['x'];
        $y= $_SESSION['y'];
        require_once '../models/Connection.php';
        require_once '../models/User.php';
        $User = new User();
        $User->deleteToken($selector .  $validator);
    }
    session_destroy();
    if (isset($_COOKIE['sessionPAD'])) { //to try to delet cookie
        unset($_COOKIE['sessionPAD']);
        setcookie("sessionPAD", null, -1, "../");
        setcookie("sessionPAD", null, -1, "/");
        setcookie("sessionPAD", null, -1);
    }
    var_dump($_COOKIE); //When I see the result of this sessionPAD is not shown, so I guess session was deleted or can't be seen from that file
    //header("location:../"); //line commented to test
```

After logging out I go to `index.php` and guess what, the cookie with the same values is still there.

I have seen code to remove all cookies but I just want to remove that cookie in specific.

*Thanks a lot for your time guys*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

Hi guys, after a lot of time trying different options I found out how to remove that cookie

```
setcookie($name, '', -1, "/", "www.eg.eg", true);
```

My explanation:

As I'm using SSL I set the cookie to be available in secure connections and also just to be available in my domain, so to unset the cookie I need to specify the same parameters, domain and secure connection only.

*After all it wasn't a folder's thing but a parameter's thing*